# User-defined variables support in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, user-variables

Does SQLAlchemy have support for user-defined variables?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html

Problem: I am trying to get the time difference between two consecutive rows. I can do this by writing raw SQL query using user-defined variables. Is this possible to do in SQLAlchemy without writing raw SQL query?

My table is something like this:

```
id user_id date
1. user_1  01-11-2021 00:00
2. user_1  01-11-2021 00:00
3. user_1  01-11-2021 00:01
4. user_2  01-11-2021 00:00
```

Output would be something like

```
id user_id time_diff
1. user_1  NULL
2. user_1  0
3. user_1  1
4. user_2  NULL
```

Comment: *Does SQLAlchemy have support for user-defined variables?* User-defined MySQL variables are not accessible by external script. But you may use them in raw SQL query. *Is this possible to do in SQLAlchemy without writing raw SQL query?* Yes, you may build a query which uses 3 copies of source table.

Comment: @Akina _User-defined MySQL variables are not accessible by external script._ Why is that the case? Can you explain or link to a page where it explains this?

Comment: If external script wants to know the value of UDV it must query it (like `SELECT @variable'`) and receive the value. No another way. No the possibility to access the variable other than quering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query which performs needed task and does not use UDV and is applicable in MySQL 5.6 looks like:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.date, t2.date) time_diff
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
                  AND t1.date > t2.date
LEFT JOIN table t3 ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id 
                  AND t1.date > t3.date
                  AND t3.date > t2.date
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
```

The logic: we select 2 rows (by `date` value) for a user from table copies `t1` and `t2` (and row in `t2` have earlier `date` value), and the copy `t3` checks that these rows are really adjacent (there is no third row between them).

This query does not use UDV and can be converted to SQLAlchemy syntax.

Comment: I wanted to use this as a subquery and get the overall time spent for all the users. I am trying to avoid raw SQL query to mitigate the risks associated. But if it comes at the cost of time, I am willing to take the extra risk. My question is, does using a LEFT JOIN increase/decrease the time taken to run the query compared to UDV? Or Is it better to use UDV and substitute the input after proper validation?

Comment: @LemonReddy *I am trying to avoid raw SQL query to mitigate the risks associated.* I understand this. My query CAN be converted from raw text to framework's syntax, and you won't use raw query. *does using a LEFT JOIN increase/decrease the time taken to run the query compared to UDV?* The query which uses UDV is less expensive anycase - it uses one table copy and single-pass fullscan which must be more fast than joining 3 table copies, even when suitable indexes exists.